# My image keeps getting pushed to the left with this jquery code

Tags: jquery, css

I have 4 images:

```
                 image 1     image 2



                 image 3     image 4
```

When I click image 1 a jquery slider comes down. The only problem is when image 3 and 4 are set to absolute positioning it doesn't push them down like I want it to. When they are set to relative positioning it pushes them down but then pushes them off to the left. How do I make it not do this?

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Set a `margin-left` equals to the `width` of the content on the left of these menus.

Without looking at your code I can't provide an accurate answer, but maybe you can get an [idea from this example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VV44Z/).